# getRealPath(“/”)- How does the result of this method differ in Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8

Tags: web-services, jsp, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat8

Using this method

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
```

returns '\' at the end when i run my project in Tomcat 7 whereas it is not working as such in Tomcat 8.

For example,

In Tomcat 7 it returns as "D:\Tomcat\webapps\project\"

In Tomcat 8 it returns as "D:\Tomcat\webapps\project"

At present the project is in production so, I am unable to change the code in every part(where i use `getRealPath("/")`). Is there a way/setting in tomcat level to make it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been Fixed in trunk for 9.0.x and in 8.0.x for 8.0.19 onwards.

For your reference,

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57556